# xml flattening using python

Tags: python, xml-parsing, flatten

I am trying to flatten an xml and write to a csv so that it can be used by etl process.

```
<Answers>
      <AnswersList>
        <Entry key="qs_location_name" type="System.String">
          <value>Location Name</value>
        </Entry>
        <Entry key="qs_location_riskAddress1" type="System.String">
          <value>Risk Address 1</value>
        </Entry>
        <Entry key="qs_location_riskAddress2" type="System.String">
          <value>Risk Address 2</value>
        </Entry>
</AnswersList>
</Answers>
```

My code is as below

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(xml_file))

root = tree.getroot().tag
for node in tree.iter():
    for child in node.getchildren():
        if child.text:
          if child.text.strip():
            print("{}.{} = {}".format(root, ".".join(tree.getelementpath(child).split("/")), child.text.strip()))
```

The above code provides the below output.

```
AustraliaBizPackProposal.Answers.AnswersList.Entry[1].value = Location Name
AustraliaBizPackProposal.Answers.AnswersList.Entry[2].value = Risk Address 1
AustraliaBizPackProposal.Answers.AnswersList.Entry[3].value = Risk Address 2
```

My expected output is to generate it as below, please advise

```
AustraliaBizPackProposal.Answers.AnswersList.qs_location_name.value = Location Name
AustraliaBizPackProposal.Answers.AnswersList.qs_location_riskAddress1.value = Risk Address 1
AustraliaBizPackProposal.Answers.AnswersList.qs_location_riskAddress2.value = Risk Address 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for this specific file:

```
root = tree.getroot().tag
for node in tree.iter():
for child in node.getchildren():
    if child.tag == 'Entry':            
        path = tree.getelementpath(child).split("/")[0]
        key = child.attrib['key']
        for val in child.getchildren(): 
            try:                    
                print("{}.{}.{}.{} = {}".format(root, path, key, val.tag, val.text.strip()))
            except:
                print("{}.{}.{}.{} = {}".format(root, path, key, val.tag, val.attrib['Text']))
```

Comment: Great! please accept the answer so your question gets marked as answered and others can get benefit from it.

Comment: The below child tags are not getting parsed . Any idea on the same. <Entry key="qs_businessInterruption_indemnityPeriod"       type="Ace.ePolicy.Framework.Question.Answer">
      <value ID="3" Text="12 months" />
    </Entry>

Comment: in this case the child tag <value> has the text as an attribute and not as a child, the code was updated to treat this case.